# Call a PyQt class from inside Watchdog event handler class

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, watchdog, python-watchdog

I have watchdog set up to monitor a folder for new files and I want to try to get back to the main PyQt class after it runs the on_created function.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class CreatedEvent(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_created(self, event):
        #some code
```

I need to be able to call someFunction

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class someClass(QMainWindow):
    def someFunction(self):
        #some code
```

I have tried using signals but I always get this error

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```